# Magento2 product distance sort and filter

Tags: magento2, filter, product-sorting

I need a custom extension for Magento2 - sort and filter product distance with map.
Its [extension](https://www.commerceextensions.com/free-product-distance-sort-magento-1.html) for m1 i needed to m2
I try converter code m1 to m2 but - but lack of knowledge (
Please help anybody, maybe someone solved a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

MageModule's Product Distance Sort & Filter extension allows customers to sort product lists on Category and Search Results pages by distance from their location and also filter the product list by a distance range from their location. It's simple: add address information or even very general location information like Mount Rushmore or New York City to some products. Using that information, either Google or Bing will automatically provide the latitude and longitude coordinates for the product’s location and it will be automatically saved to the product. On the front end, the customer’s location will be automatically obtained from their IP address and the distance calculation will happen on the fly. Additionally, the products will be plotted out on a Google map for a helpful visual reference.

https://www.magemodule.com/product-distance-sort-filter/

Comment: I need this on Magento2 - your extension on Magento1 (